# Problem with UPDATE MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bit of an issue with my code.

I'm making an administrative panel for users to add things to the database.  On occasion, they might try to save data without changing it (open a dialog, click save without changing anything).  This, of course, will make mysql_affected_rows() return '0' when checking to see if the UPDATE query worked.

Is there another query to make that will always UPDATE regardless of whether the data is the same or not (or can I modify a simple UPDATE query to always update)?

*EDIT*

This is for users who don't have programming experience.  Of course you wouldn't want to update if there's no reason to, but when a user tries to update and it doesn't happen I end up showing a failure message.  Rather than there being something wrong, its just it doesn't need to be updated.  I need a way to show the user that, instead of a generic 'failure' message.  If it failed for another reason, I still need to know.

Comment: MySQL is smart enough, not to make unnecessary updates - so why did you want to? I just simply print a message like 'Nothing to save here - no changes found.' to the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the MySQL Documentation:

> If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this
>   and does not update it.

Instead of checking `mysql_affected_rows`, just check to see if the query was successful:

```
if(!mysql_query("UPDATE ..."))
{ 
  //failure
}
else
{
    $verification = mysql_query("SELECT ROW_COUNT() as rows_affected");
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($verification);
    $rows_affected = $row[0];

    if ($rows_affected > 0)
    {
        //update was performed
    }
    else
    {
        //no update was needed
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my entry to aim at more of what I'm looking for, hopefully.

Comment: @Phillip: To show an error to your users, just populate the `if` block in the code above with a `die(mysql_error())`. You could also log the error in another table for further investigation.

Comment: The only problem with that is that there is no error to report when the data is already there (which is my problem).  It'd be great if it'd spit out something dealing with that but its not.  It also seems inefficient to run another query just to see if the data is the same.

Comment: @Phillip: So, if I understand correctly, you want to alert your users that no update was performed because the entered data was already in the table?

Comment: Yes correct.  But if there was another reason for the query not updating, I need to present them with that as well.

Comment: @Phillip: I added to the code snippet. The verification query is extremely fast since it only fetches one variable from memory, so it won't affect performance.

Comment: But that is exactly what you want, isn't it? If there is an error, you show an error. If there is no error (even if the number of affected rows is 0), you don't display an error message. As another approach you could update the timestamp from your query, so the row will always be changed.

Comment: That's right that MySQL doesn't update it and that is why no rows are affected as mentioned by Philip. But I think that has nothing to do with mysql_query() that returns TRUE or FALSE depending on whether the query successfully executed or not irrespective if it made any data changes